# Springboot war deployed on external tomcat but 404

Tags: spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I have a project on tomcat and it works on spring but when i tried to deployed on a external tomcat i get 404 error

i've tried a lot of things but i cant fix it

my main class

i saw that

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
        @Resource
     // FileStorageService storageService;
        
        FileStorageService storageService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RApplication.class, args);
    }
      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
          return builder.sources(RApplication.class);
      }
      @Override
      public void run(String... arg) throws Exception {
        storageService.deleteAll();
        storageService.init();
      }

}
```

and my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.r</groupId>
    <artifactId>RD</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>RDrone</name>
    <description>Portal Web</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-validation</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
     <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i already trie tu create exlusions on spring web dependency
and create servlet dependecy on my maven but it doesnt work

I think that the problem is on my projectt but i dont know if it could be something on my tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a spring boot application, Tomcat server comes embedded, which means you do not need to worry about deploying your JAR/WAR file on external tomcat server. Your question seems invalid here can you elaborate more on what exactly you are trying to do ? Your POM.xml has more than required dependencies for a spring boot application to boot up !

Comment: Yeah i know that spring has server embedded but i want to deploy the app in a external server

My pom could bbe the problem for the denependencies ?